# Is it possible to enumerate the field names of an ADO Recordset with JavaScript and cscript?

Tags: javascript, ado, wsh

I am writing some scripts to run on old Windows NT machines. I am planning on using the command-based script host (cscript) to execute them. The script are querying some SQL data and I want to retrieve the field names from the RecordSet, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
rs.open(query, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly);


rs.MoveFirst();
while(!rs.eof) {
 for(field in rs.Fields) {
  WScript.Echo(field.Name); /* outputs nothing */

 }
    WScript.Echo(rs.Fields("column")); /* outputs the column value for this record (as expected)*/

 rs.MoveNext();
}

rs.close();
```

**Edit:**

Tried this as well:

```
while(!rs.eof) {
    WScript.Echo(rs.Fields.length); /* doesn't print anything */
    for(var i = 0; i< rs.Fields.length; i++) { /* loop isn't entered */
        WScript.Echo(rs.Fields(i).Name);
    }
    rs.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see further back, where you create `rs`.

Also, you don't have `On Error Resume Next` perchance, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  WScript.Echo(rs.Fields(0).Name);
```

..then interate through the index.

Comment: try: WScript.Echo(rs.Fields.count);